# member function pointer - how to do this?

Tags: c++

I have the following:

```
    class NetRequest: public QObject {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:

            NetRequest(QString postData, void(BrowserApp::*f)(QByteArray));
            QString postData;
            void (BrowserApp::*fn)(QByteArray);
        public slots:
            void requestFinished(QNetworkReply *r);
        }
```

and the cpp is:

```
        NetRequest::NetRequest(QString postData, void(BrowserApp::*f)(QByteArray)) {
            this->postData = postData;
            this->fn = f;
        }

        void NetRequest::requestFinished(QNetworkReply *r) {
            QByteArray data;
                fn(data);<--- this doesn't work
        }
```

I am trying to call the function "fn" in requestFinished but the compiler doesn't let me - what am I please doing wrong?

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: The correct call syntax should be `this->(*fn)(data);`

Comment: Sorry, not `this->`, but a valid pointer to a `BrowserApp` instance is needed!

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an error message.

Comment: @g-makulik:  I believe it's actually `(this->*fn)(data);`

Comment: @JohnDibling You're right (I'm always hardly remembering this), the crucial part is the `->*`, which forms an operator of it's own.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a pointer-to-member-function, in order to call through it you must also have a pointer to the object you are using for the call.

But your code:

```
fn(data);
```

Has no such object pointer.  You probably are assuming that an object is associated with the member function pointer -- but it isn't.

Try this:

```
(that->*fn)(data);
```

`that` is a pointer to a `BrowserApp` object.  It will need to be either passed in to the `requestFinished` function, or somehow stored in the `NetRequest` object -- probably at the same time when `fn` is set.

Comment: But `this` is a `NetRequest`, not `BrowserApp`.

Comment: @Neet:  Take another peek.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). They will help you in many ways when it comes to "function pointers".

Then it would look something like this instead:

```
class NetRequest: public QObject {
    std::function<void(QByteArray)> fn;

    // ...

public:
    NetRequest::NetRequest(QString postData, std::function<void(QByteArray)> f) {
        // ...
        fn = f;
    }

    // ...
};
```

Now when creating an instance of the `NetRequest` object, you must use `std::bind` to bind a function from the `BrowserApp` class to the `std::function` object:

```
BrowserApp app;

NetRequest request("some string", std::bind(&BrowserApp::SomeFunction, app));
```

---

The nice thing about using `std::function` is that the callback function no longer have to be a `BrowserApp` member function, it can by *any* function, including lambda expressions.

Comment: Assuming the OP wants to use/can use/uses C++11.